# How to play Diablo III in a Virtual Machine?

Tags: diablo-iii, graphics-card, virtualization

I saw a lot of people asking the same question in other forums (yes, i've googled it a little bit), and some people answered that of course is possible to play it in a Virtual Machine but only using **VMWare**, some other people said that isn't possible even in **VMWare**, and the people who said that it's possible and also who said they have virtualized **Diablo III** doesn't gave proofs.

I know that **VirtualBox** application does not offer GPU support, the Video Card is completelly virtualized and only has 256 MB, so is not possible to run/play **Diablo III** (i've tried it), now I'm trying to play in **VMWare Workstation** 'cause it have physical access to the host graphics and GPU acceleration and I've read that **Diablo III** can be played with **VMWare**, well, I've installed **VMWare guest tools pack**, and I've installed and updated **Diablo III** from the **Battle.Net** app, but when I try to run the game it seems to load but it only shows a black screen after the loading screen (but I can hear the music foreground game and I can see the **Diablo III** custom cursor on the black screen)

My host OS is Windows 8.1 x64, guest OS is **Windows 7 x86**, with **4 GB** of virtual memory, I have an **nVidia GTX 650** video card, and I've tried to run **Diablo III Reaper of souls**.

I've installed the last **DirectX** and the **.NET Framework 4.5** on the guest *OS*, I've also tried to specify different compatibility checks on the game executable, but nothing changed, I still can't see/play the game.

So... if someone is really able to play **Diablo III** on a *VirtualMachine* please illustrate me with the steps to reproduce it with all the details such as the *OS*, the *OS* arquitecture, the given virtual memory, libraries/software installed, **diablo3** or **diablo3-Reaper of souls** etc... ...everything.

Thankyou for read.

Comment: In your VM, what graphics card does it report?

Comment: @TZHX With Speccy application it reports an `VMware SVGA 3D (VMware)` ...I need to install something more?. thanks for comment

Comment: @ElektroStudios - You have to have a specific hardware visualization support to do this, your hardware, does not have that support.

Comment: I presume you have Mac OS X as host OS. Why don't you use the native versions of the Battle.Net client and Diablo 3 / RoS?

Comment: @Bora My host OS is Windows 8.1 x64 (where I can play perfectlly to Diablo III-RoS)

Comment: @Ramhound `You have to have specific hardware visualization support` please could you say me what you mean with 'hardware visualization' ? what I require?

Answer (score 5):

I was testing and playing with the config file (desperately), and in my specific case the solution was to use Windowed Mode, so I can't run at Full-Screen but Windowed mode works perfectly.

Just open (or copy from Host OS) the config file `D3Prefs.txt` stored at `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Diablo III` and change this value

```
DisplayModeWindowMode "0"
```

From **False** (0) to **True** (1):

```
DisplayModeWindowMode "1"
```

And no other things are needed like installing drivers or anything else, just change that setting in the VM to run the game in an isolated Window.

For some, setting vsync on (from 0 to 1) also corrects the issue and allows full screen support.

PS: I've tested it in **VMWare** and don't expect that this could work in **VirtualBox**.

PS2: Not even the game installation is required - the entire **Diablo III** folder can be copied from Host OS and it should work perfectly fine (at least in my case).

Comment: This solved my problem of "d3d error" in a non-virtualized Windows 7 on a Lenove E530. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually i have managed to let it run in vmwareplayer...
My laptop is a lenovo g500 with i5 3rd gen. 8gb ram 2gb graphic card with win8 running.
I started a win7 vm with 3vcores and 5gb ram 3d acceleration enabled and vmware tools ...
After some d3prefs customization i found on a website i could run d3 with mid performance and like 40fps ...
Just my 2 cents.